# What is the correct way to write date-time in ISO 8601 format when milliseconds has less than 3 digits?

Tags: datetime, datetime-format, iso8601

Here is and example of date-time moment of time in ISO 8601 with milliseconds:

```
2024-03-02T17:13:07.123Z
```

What is the correct way to write date-time if case the milliseconds part consists not of 3 digits, but from smaller number of digits (the milliseconds part is less than 100 milliseconds).

For example, if the milliseconds number is 15, so 15 milliseconds past the whole second, how the string should be written?

```
2024-03-02T17:13:07.15Z
```

or

```
2024-03-02T17:13:07.015Z
```

?

And if the milliseconds part is equal to zero there are many possible ways to write it, but what is the correct one to use?

```
2024-03-02T17:13:07.0Z
```

or

```
2024-03-02T17:13:07.Z
```

or

```
2024-03-02T17:13:07.000Z
```

?

Can you please quote the relevant part of the documentation that states how this situation should be handled?

Comment: Why do you think that `15` milliseconds would be something different than `0.015` seconds?

Comment: Regarding *precision*, i.e. number of decimal places: that's up to your use-case, ISO 8601 doesn't specify a limit AFAIK. So e.g. femtoseconds = 15 digits are allowed but might be inappropriate.

Comment: 7.15 and 7.015 are very different things. Which one do you mean? Whichever it is, that is the one you should write. "Can you please quote the relevant part of the documentation" You want us to read the documentation to you?

Comment: @Progman I'm working with API of some service. It is returning date-time without leading zeros in milliseconds part— so I get something like `2024-03-02T17:13:07.15Z` from the service. The first version of my code didn't work with such dates, so I had to fix it. I want to understand how common this format is. It is just a badly created service, or such strings are completely normal. In case it is clear that this is wrong, and I have some links to specs that states how the date-time should be formatted then I can write to the owners of the service and ask them to change the behaviour.

Comment: @matt I'm sorry I don't quite understand the question. I'm asking — what is the preffered way to write a string in iso8601 format that points to the moment of time of year 2024, March, 2 17:13:07 UTC and with 15 milliseconds after the start of the second.

Comment: @matt "You want us to read the documentation to you?" I wan't able to find the answer in the documentation, so I'm asking the community with the hope that the community can help me find the answer.

Comment: *"It is returning date-time without leading zeros in milliseconds part*" - the decimal part after the seconds is not a "milliseconds part" in ISO8601. It's fractional seconds. `xx.15` means xx seconds plus 150 ms or 150000 us or 150000000 ns etc. It's whatever makes sense in your use case. If 1/100th of a second (2 decimal places) is appropriate, use it. If you write an ISO8601 parser, make it accept any number of decimal places. If you use a parser that only supports ms, us, etc. - zero-fill to that precision.

Comment: @FObersteiner Thank you! After you second comment I feel that I start to understand that is going on. Huge thank you for clearly stating that the part after the dot in this notation is a fraction of a second, not the number of millisecond. (And also thank you for "femtoseconds" — I've never head this unit of time before)

Comment: `2024-03-02T17:13:07.015Z` is correct. `2024-03-02T17:13:07.15Z` would mean the same as `2024-03-02T17:13:07.150Z`. It’s a usual and ordinary decimal number. For a point in time on the whole second `2024-03-02T17:13:07.0Z`, `2024-03-02T17:13:07Z` and `2024-03-02T17:13:07.000Z` are all correct. I doubt that `2024-03-02T17:13:07.Z` is. If you leave out the decimal part, which is fine, also leave out the decimal point. I also doubt that there’s any official preference. Use the one you like best.

Comment: Since you seem to understand now, please feel free to answer your own question for the benefit of future readers. I will be happy to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, if the milliseconds number is 15, so 15 milliseconds past
> the whole second, how the string should be written?

The [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation is `2024-03-02T17:13:07.015Z`.

**Demo using Java Language**:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The second last parameter specifies nanoseconds
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(2024, 3, 2, 17, 13, 7, 15000000, ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2024-03-02T17:13:07.015Z
```

**[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/7sjlyR)**

> And if the milliseconds part is equal to zero there are many possible
> ways to write it, but what is the correct one to use?

The standard representation is `2024-03-02T17:13:07Z`.

This is where a format removes the ambiguity e.g. if you use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` as the format, your date-time object will be printed as `2024-03-02T17:13:07.000Z`. A format is just a way to represent an object for a specific use case but a representation does not change the value e.g. you can write `5` as `5.0`, `5.00`, `5.000` for your specific use case and for every use case, the value will remain `5`.

**Demo using Java Language**:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The second last parameter specifies nanoseconds
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(2024, 3, 2, 17, 13, 7, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);

        // Print it in the default format
        System.out.println(odt);

        // ######### Formatted output #########
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
        System.out.println(odt.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2024-03-02T17:13:07Z
2024-03-02T17:13:07.000Z
```

**[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/p2jICC)**

---

<sup>Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.</sup>